# ServerCertificateValidationCallback - multiple callbacks

Tags: c#, networking, static, callback

in my c# application i'm using HTTPWebrequest in order to connect to multipale machines (one per machine)
i'm using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback in order to ignore hostname mismatch errors.
I want a different callback for each machine. for part of the machines I want to ignore the error, and part of them not. 
because this property is static I failed to do it, when the error is raising all the callback are called. 
how can I do this callback for  each machine and not one per application?

thanks

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to setup your callback?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a factory of validation callbacks which would return a different callback depending on the certificate.

Then, in the static shared callback you'd refer to the factory, get a proper callback and execute it.

Comment: This could also be done on the `sender` parameter, albeit this is an `object` that first needs to be casted to f.ex. a `WebRequest`.